# Explanation of commit line in a git log entry

Tags: git, git-log

Sometimes I see a lot of branching information when I call a `git log` on my repo. For example:

```
commit COMMIT_HASH (HEAD -> CURRENT_BRANCH, tag: A_TAG, ANOTHER_BRANCH, ANOTHER_BRANCH)
Author: AUTHOR_NAME
Date: DATE

    LOG MESSAGE
```

My question is about part in the first line of the message. After the `COMMIT_HASH` theres some information about what I believe is some kind history of the branch. In honesty, I did not go through the whole description of `git log`; however, I could not find the description of its output format. An explanation or a link to the information would be appreciated.

Comment: It is just showing you what the HEAD points to, and also what are the tags for that commit.

Comment: does this mean this head points to all the 4 things mentioned? i.e. this head points to CURRENT_BRANCH, A_TAG, ANOTHER_BRANCH, ANOTHER_BRANCH?

Comment: @SpaceMonkey55 edited my answer to adress that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's called "decorations". It shows which refs are currently pointing to this commit.

You can control the display of this information with `--decorate` (by default) / `--no-decorate`. ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorateshortfullautono))

---

And to answer your question in comment (does this mean this head points to all the 4 things mentioned?) :

No. `HEAD` points only to one thing. Typically, the currently checked out branch, but it could be just a commit (in case of detached HEAD state). You can have other refs which happen to point to the same commit, but `HEAD` only points to one.